# Get the id from a Img without the ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating  a simple bootstrap gallery thumbnail with images that are being called from database. I succeed in calling all the info, but now i'm struggling with getting the id of each image. This is my code:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>" src="<?php echo $row['category_image'] ?>" alt="<?php $row['Categories'] ?>">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><?php echo $row['ID_Category']?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['Categories'] ?></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="return getID(this);" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my function in javascript:

```
function getID(e)
{
    var x = e.src;
    alert(x);
}
```

But it is not working, how do I get the id of each image if is being called from a database?

Comment: what r u trying to get? the id or src?

Comment: "this" is the link button.

Comment: Im trying to get the ID from the image when the user click at the <a> tag that is a button

Comment: @Hodrobond assuming OP has jquery.

Comment: without jquery its possible?

Comment: oh solved it, sorry for my ignorance im kind of new using javascript. thank you for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you get in the same way you wrote?

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>" src="<?php echo $row['category_image'] ?>" alt="<?php $row['Categories'] ?>">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><?php echo $row['ID_Category']?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['Categories'] ?></p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="return getID(<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>);" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

function getID(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

Comment: That's a way to solve my problem. Its useful so i will check it as an answer, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Attribute tag in a tag and add onclick function to get your id value . i set `category-id` Attribute and in javascript code use this tag to get value

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>" src="<?php echo $row['category_image'] ?>" alt="<?php $row['Categories'] ?>">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><?php echo $row['ID_Category']?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['Categories'] ?></p>
   <p><a href="#" onclick="return getID(this);" category-id="<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

then this is script function

```
<script>
function getID(obj)
{
    alert(obj.getAttribute("category-id"));
}
</script>
```

or add onclick function and send id in this function

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>" src="<?php echo $row['category_image'] ?>" alt="<?php $row['Categories'] ?>">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3><?php echo $row['ID_Category']?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row['Categories'] ?></p>
   <p><a href="#" onclick="return getID('<?php echo $row['ID_Category']?>');"  class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is script

```
<script>
function getID(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

both will work.

Comment: Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: @Alessandro yes question provider use id so i think this id is unique so it is no problem

Comment: In the above solution the `img` element and the `a` element have the same id

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getID(obj){
   if(obj instanceof HTMLElement) {
    alert(obj.getAttribute("data-target-id"));
   }
   else {
    alert(obj);
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png/320px-PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" alt="test test">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Example 1</h3>
    <p>Using data-* attribute</p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="getID(this);" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-target-id="1">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="2" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png/320px-PM5544_with_non-PAL_signals.png" alt="test test">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Example 2</h3>
    <p>Passing id directly</p>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="getID(1);" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of only code answers, please explain the code you provided or why you added/changed something specifically.